# Test Production Build Locally

Tags: vue.js, gridsome

I'm running into a bit of a wall and hoping for some help. It's probably something really simple that I'm overlooking. Our team is working on our lighthouse score, mainly focused on mobile optimization. Is it possible to actually build and serve those compiled files locally? What's the best way to do that and test what our performance is?

Comment: "those compiled files"?  What compiled files?  Maybe it's clear to someone who could help you, and so you'll get a helpful answer, but the goal of SO is not to help just one individual but rather to build a widely useful knowledge base.  Your question could benefit a lot by some detail as to what you're talking about. - Also, the subject of a question is important.  Yours says pretty much nothing about your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it from a high level, you are building your Vue application into a static website. Static websites only require a simple HTTP server. Therefore you can host and test this production build two different ways:

1. With a simple local HTTP server (apache, nginx, node express), or you could use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server
2. Host your production build online somewhere, such as https://pages.github.com/